# Difference in threading.Thread(target=sample_function), args=[arg1]) from threading.Thread(target=sample_function(arg1))

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I've been working around a threading functionality inside a loop and this caught my attention.
If I execute

```
threading.Thread(target=sample_function(arg1))
```

It doesn't actually multithread as expected, instead it had to go through the entire `sample_function()` before starting the second one.
Turns out i had to change to this line instead to get proper multithreading

```
threading.Thread(target=sample_function, args=[arg1])
```

Can anyone tell me why is this so?

Thanks!

Comment: The rules here are not different from anywhere else. If your argument to `threading.Thread` involve a function call, that one is executed first. Expecting something magical to multithread at that point is just wrong, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The `target=` is expected to be a callable. `sample_function` is callable. `sample_function(arg1)` isn't callable, but the return of the function call.

I assume that `sample_function(arg1)` returns `None` which makes `threading.Thread(target=sample_function(arg1))` run nothing.

For edutainment purposes: make samplefunction return a string and see what happens